# Python: Get latest date time in a simple string

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, time

How do I get the latest time every time I print a string:

I used the below code:

---

```
t1 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
s1 = "%s is a programming %s since" +" "+ t1 
s2 = s1%(Einstein, genius)
```

---

When I run this code - the time t1 shows a constant time value:

```
print (s2)
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 17:33:57.484815
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 17:33:57.484815
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 17:33:57.484815
```

Is there a way to auto-update the value of "t1", or in other words, How can I have the time updated every time I run the code?
like for e.g.:

```
print(s2)
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 17:33:57.484815
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 17:34:13.484815
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 17:35:26.484815
```

Thank you in advance.

(I am but an absolute neophyte to programming and python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not have 'magic' variables that change their value by themselves. A reference to a variable such as `s2` will cause it to look up the same object that you put in there the last time you assigned something to it - and it will stay the same. To make Python **do** something every time you refer to it, you might want to use a function, instead. e.g., make s2 be a function, like this:

```
def s2():
    t1 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    s1 = "%s is a programming %s since" +" "+ t1 
    return s1%("Einstein", "genius")
```

Now, use `s2()` where you used just `s2` in your code, and Python will re-execute your code and produce a new string with the current date/time in it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had literally no idea how to define a function - or what function is. Your guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the datetime directly to the string instead of storing it in a variable.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
import time

s = "%s is a programming %s since %s"
print ( s %("Einstein", "genius", datetime.datetime.now()))
time.sleep(5)
print (s %("Einstein", "genius", datetime.datetime.now()))
```

**Output:**

```
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 19:07:15.697000
Einstein is a programming genius since 2018-06-24 19:07:20.700000
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, I shall try this code too. Leo's code for my understanding - for where I am now in terms of coding prowess, seemed easier to understand. Thanks a ton for taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function returning the value that should be up-to-date:

```
def make_time():
    return str(datetime.datetime.now())

s = "%s is a programming %s since %%s" % ("Einstein", "genius")
print(s % make_time())
print(s % make_time())
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene. Shall try this code and keep it in mind as an alternative.